# Counting vowels and consonants

Tags: c++

My program keeps crashing every time I enter an input even though I use a system pause method and displays the same number of vowels and consonants that is incorrect. What's going on?

```
int main() {
    // declare vars
    char ch;
    int vowels = 0;
    int consonants = 0;
    string word = "temp";

    // prompt user
    cout << "Please enter a word: ";
    cin >> ch;

    // loop vowels and consonants
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
        ch = toupper(word[i]);
        switch (ch) {
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'O':
        case 'U':
            vowels++;
            break;
        default:
            consonants++;
        }
    }

    // show num of vowels and consanants
    cout << "Number of Vowels: " << vowels << endl;
    cout << "Number of Consanants: " << consonants << endl;

    // pause and exit
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin >> ch;` => `cin >> word;` for starters.

Comment: Your code is not reading the `word` correctly. Rather than using `cin >> ch`, use `cin >> word`. It's not supposed to crash, though.

Comment: I'm curious on why it crashes, though.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some chages in your code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // declare vars
    char ch;
    int vowels = 0;
    int consonants = 0;
    string word = "temp";

    // prompt user
    cout << "Please enter a word: ";
    cin >> word;

    // loop vowels and consonants
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
        ch = toupper(word[i]);
        switch (ch) {
        case 'A':
            vowels++;
            break;
        case 'E':
            vowels++;
            break;
        case 'I':
            vowels++;
            break;
        case 'O':
            vowels++;
            break;
        case 'U':
            vowels++;
            break;
        default:
            consonants++;
        }
    }

    // show num of vowels and consanants
    cout << "Number of Vowels: " << vowels << endl;
    cout << "Number of Consanants: " << consonants << endl;

    // pause and exit
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ben I dont need a comments to change this code ok? Dont write a foolish comments to here again.

Comment: I've added the vowels++ and break statements to each vowel and works perfectly thanks!

Comment: @Revert That part of the change is insignificant, the fallthrough method you have is fine. The only change made here that means anything is the `cin >> word;` part.

Comment: @CherkesgillerTural You copied the entire code changed the switch statement which is meaningless because it worked before. Changed the `cin >> word;` part (which is the only thing that counts). Your whole answer could have just been change `cin >> ch;` to `cin >> word;`. You have literally changed nothing else. Want proof: http://ideone.com/8nGoBZ

Just saying that you have too much bloat in your answer. Also that attitude wont serve you very well on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it's better to input a full string and then parse... but if for some reason you need to stream characters as they are entered you can use `cin.get()`. make sure to `#include <cctype>` if you want to use `toupper()`.

```
char nextChar;
nextChar = cin.get();
nextChar = toupper(nextChar);

int consonants = 0;
int vowels = 0;
int words = 0;

while (nextChar != '\n')
{
    switch (nextChar)
    {
    case 'A':
    case 'E':
    case 'I':
    case 'O':
    case 'U':
        vowels++:
        break;
    case ' ':
        words++;
        break;
    default:
        consonants++;
        break;
    }
}
cout << "There were " << consonants << " consonants and " << vowels << " vowels in " << words << " words.";
```

instead of ending on a newline, if you want to limit to one word simply replace `(nextChar != '\n')` with `(nextChar != ' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

The only change that needs to occur is the change from:

```
cin >> ch;
```

to

```
cin >> word;
```

And you code will be fine. [Live example](http://ideone.com/8nGoBZ)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so this isn't quite an answer, but it's a bit too detailed to put into a comment...

I just ran your code and it worked fine. I added the following three libraries

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
```

And then:

```
using namespace std;
```

and then compiled with `g++ filename`.

Check to make sure you're libraries are up to date and that you're compiling the code correctly.

Hope this helps.